# How to execute Here Fuel API using api key?

Tags: here-api

I am trying to execute the fuel API, but it is not working and throwing unauthorized error. I am using app code & api key in my request. Is this not supported?

```
curl -v -X GET https://fuel-v2.cc.api.here.com/fuel/fueltypes.json?app_id={APP_ID}&app_key={API_KEY}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Fuel Prices API is for in-vehicle applications only and not part of the Freemium plan. (Note that it uses app_id/app_code instead of the apiKey authentication used for Freemium APIs.) You can use the contact us form to request access if you have a relevant use case.